# What if the LDO feedback resistor has higher value, how it will affect the feedback current?

Tags: voltage, ldo

Following is the application digram of [LDO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bckU2.png).
[image]

I have calculated the resistor values R1 and R2 under the assumption of following recommendaton (R1||R2 = 250 kΩ).
[image]

Calculated values are R1 = 517.38 kΩ and R2 = 483.7 kΩ.

Can this higher resistor values affect the feedback current or the perfomance of LDO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps735.pdf?ts=1625022325636&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS735) recommended value for R1 is 110k\$\Omega\$. Using 4-5x higher values will mean potentially more error from variations in the feedback input bias current.

It is specified as +/-500nA worst-case over the temperature range. With a 250K R1||R2 as you have, the worst-case error would be +/-125mV at the feedback pin, or about +/-10% at the regulator output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNeTAe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see from the simulation, the numbers work out and the variation is from 2.242V to 2.76V (plus whatever additional error is contributed by the resistor tolerances and drifts, and the reference voltage tolerance and drift).

Also the compensation capacitor has to be adjusted as noted in your question.

Comment: I am a bit confused with R1||R2 recommendation, Is it mandatory to keep the R1||R2 = 250 kΩ? FYI, 110 kΩ is R1, not R2

Comment: R1 ~= 110k and R1||R2 ~= 250k are obviously incompatible. I suggest keeping the values relatively low. For example if R1 = 110K, then R2 ~= 102K (standard values). Nominal Vout becomes 2.51V.